# Mathematica giving incorrect result for implicit equation $x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} = 1$?

Tags: plotting, implicit

When I type the following implicit equation into Mathematica I only get 'one quarter' of what the resulting plot should look like, i.e., I only get the upper-right quadrant.

```
ContourPlot[x^(2/3) + y^(2/3) == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

If you type $x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} = 1$ into [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) graphing calculator you will see the correct output which has a curve in each of the four quadrants.

So why is Mathematica giving an incorrect result, and is it possible to make it plot this implicit function correctly?

Comment: Try `ContourPlot[Abs[x]^(2/3) + Abs[y]^(2/3) == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`. _Mathematica_ is giving the correct result; for instance, how to plot `(-0.5)^(2/3)` ?

Comment: `ContourPlot[CubeRoot[x^2]+CubeRoot[y^2]==1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]` or `ContourPlot[(x^2)^(1/3)+(y^2)^(1/3)==1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]`

Comment: The calculator is apparently interpreting `x^(a/b)` as `(x^a)^(1/b)` whereas in Mathematica this is treated as `(x^(1/b))^a`. The two are of course not the same. The Mathematica treatment is a consequence of defining `x^y` as (in more customary notation) `exp(y*log(x))`

Comment: `ContourPlot[(x^2)^(1/3) + (y^2)^(1/3) == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`